# Date value of datetime column using FLUENT in laravel 5.0

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, laravel-5, fluent

How could i get only de date of a datetime column in laravel 5 using fluent?

I want to compare this `2015-08-30 23:00:00` with this:

```
    $dt = Carbon::now();
    $d = $dt->toDateString();//this is the date only which i want to compare
```

There is a mysql function called **DATE** which extract the date part of a date or datetime expression like this `` DATE(`datetime`) `` but if i use it it gives me a integrity error.

Here's how i tried to use it:

```
$reservations = \DB::table('reservations')
            ->select('reservations.id','DATE(reservations.datetime)')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody answered so i'll post how i solved it temporary:

Laravel provides something called [Raw Expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions), so i what i did was use a raw select to get the date string of a datetime like this:

```
     $reservations = \DB::table('reservations')
        ->select(\DB::raw('reservations.id, DATE(reservations.datetime)')
        ->get();
```

My goal was to compare a date from a datetime column with a `Carbon` date and here's how i did it:

```
     $dt = Carbon::now();
     $d = $dt->toDateString();//Only date from datetime

     $reservations = \DB::table('reservations')
        ->whereRaw("DATE(reservations.datetime) = '".$d."'")
        ->select(\DB::raw('reservations.id, DATE(reservations.datetime)')
        ->get();
```

I used `whereRaw` to make a Raw sentence for the where clause.

If someone has a better way of do this same thing, maybe using Eloquent i would like to know it since Eloquent is a bit more secure...

Answer (score 4):

**Follow the code to get the all of record in the date '2016-07-14' by using it**

```
 whereDate('date','=','2016-07-14')
```

**if your date is available in a variable $date then use the below code**

```
 whereDate('date',$date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it and what you are looking for is this:

```
$query->whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
```

See here for more details for `whereDate()`:
http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereDate
http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereDate` for compare only date. flow bellow code.

```
whereDate('date', '=', $date)
```

If you give whereDate then compare only date from datetime field.